# Model Objects In Swift

Tags: class, swift, struct, model

I'm struggling to design a model that will store results from an algorithm that I'm creating. The current visual structure of the model is to be as follows:

```
                                  Array Of Results
                        (containing a Dictionary where...)
                         _______________|_______________
                        |                               |
                        ^                               ^
             (Key: Letter of Alphabet)         (Value: Array of Tuples)
```

I've tried creating Classes and Structs by following tutorials, blogs and similarly asked questions, however none of them addressed my issue directly. I opted to not present any code, as I think they are fundamentally flawed. I value any input.

p.s. I'm not looking to use a third-party object modeler if any do the task. Feel free to recommend some for anyone who might be looking for one, but I would like to learn how to do this from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A Tuple can be created using the type alias like this**

```
typealias Tuple = (String,Int,Double)
```

**A Tuple Array**

```
typealias TupleArray = [Tuple]
```

**A Dictionary from String to Tuple Arrays**

```
typealias DictionaryOfTuples = [String : TupleArray]
```

or

```
typealias DictionaryOfTuples = [String : [Tuple]]
```

**Can be used like this**

```
var array1:[Tuple] = [("1",1,1.0),("1",1,1.0)]
var array2 :[Tuple] = [("1",1,1.0),("1",1,1.0)]

var single :Tuple = array1[0]

var dictionary1 :DictionaryOfTuples = ["A" : array1, "B" : array2]
var dictionary2 :DictionaryOfTuples = ["C" : array1, "D" : array2]

var final_array = [dictionary1,dictionary2]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use a dictionary like this:

```
var resultDict = [String: [AnyObject]]()
```

And when you want to set the key, you can check if it is an alphabet or not.

**UPDATED**

using typealiases:

```
typealias MyTuple = (String, String, Int)
typealias MyDict = [String: MyTuple]

var arrayOfResults = [MyDict]()
```

Comment: var resultDict = [[String():[String,String,Int]()]] was my attempt. But it's too complicated. I'm looking to simplify via object mapping.

Comment: Updated again, typealiases I think provides a more elegant way.

Comment: Thanks, you guided me most of the way but @rakeshbs had a more comprehensive answer that enabled me to solve my problem.